# Deciphering a complex type declaration for AccountId

Tags: rust

This code is from `common/primitives/src/node.rs` in *Substrate*.  Can someone do a part by part break down of this type and explain the intent of each part and the overall intent?

```
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more clear one. Check it out https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/4edd24d3cc5ce3bf44fca40e48d79fbd6c94df14/primitives/src/lib.rs#L52-L62.

```rust
/// Alias to type for a signature for a transaction on the relay chain. This allows one of several
/// kinds of underlying crypto to be used, so isn't a fixed size when encoded.
pub type Signature = MultiSignature;

/// Alias to the public key used for this chain, actually a `MultiSigner`. Like the signature, this
/// also isn't a fixed size when encoded, as different cryptos have different size public keys.
pub type AccountPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;

/// Alias to the opaque account ID type for this chain, actually a `AccountId32`. This is always
/// 32 bytes.
pub type AccountId = <AccountPublic as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

First, we define the `Signature` type.

Then, we require that the `Signature` is verify-able. How? We require it has implemented the `Verify` trait.

And then, the `Verify` trait has an associate type `Signer`. We take that `Signer` as our `AccountPublic`.

Finally, we require the `AccountPublic` has implemented the `IdentifyAccount`. So, we can use its associate type `AccountId` as our `AccountId`.

---

Why do we do this?

Because this builds a relationship between these primitives types. We can easily convert/use them.