# Where does AccountId get instantiated with its concrete form?

Tags: account, accountid

In the substrate node runtime, I can see this :

```rust
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

where `Signature` is just this:

```rust
pub enum MultiSignature {
    /// An Ed25519 signature.
    Ed25519(ed25519::Signature),
    /// An Sr25519 signature.
    Sr25519(sr25519::Signature),
    /// An ECDSA/SECP256k1 signature.
    Ecdsa(ecdsa::Signature),
}
```

And then in `frame_system::Config`, I would've expected the type of `AccountId` to specify this but I a bit confused to not see that happen:

```rust
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    ...
}
```

Which leads me to my question, where does one actually specify what kind of crypto keys the chain uses for standard accounts?

Comment: Have a look at this question and let me know if there is still anything uncertain.
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/deciphering-a-complex-type-declaration-for-accountid/5388#5388

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas This is helpful but I don't feel it addresses my question. Where in the code do I tell my chain what crypto from `MultiSignature` am I using for keypairs?

Comment: Or is it the case that substrate by default supports all three crypto signatures (ECDSA, ed25519, sr25519) and that an account may be represented by any crypto pair as long as the pubkey is SS58 encodable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined offchain when an account is created. So you can choose to make an account from one of the signature schemes you can see in `Multisignature`

This is one functionality a wallet provider offers for example. Substrate provides [subkey](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/) ([code)](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/utils/subkey) and if you run:

> cargo +nightly build --package subkey --release

> ./target/release/subkey generate --help

You can see the possibility for using the different signature schemes:

[image]

Comment: Just to reiterate, you're saying I can have two accounts, alice using ecdsa and bob using sr25519 on the same runtime?

Comment: Correct that is possible